# What is this usage of operator keyword in C++, which is followed by another class?

Tags: c++, templates, operator-keyword, class-members

In [ArrayFire](https://github.com/arrayfire/arrayfire) source code, the definition of class Array (src/backend/cuda/Array.hpp) contains:

```cpp
template<typename T>
class Array {
...

    operator Param<data_t<T>>() {
        return Param<data_t<T>>(this->get(), this->dims().get(),
                                        this->strides().get());
    }

    operator CParam<data_t<T>>() const {
        return CParam<data_t<T>>(this->get(), this->dims().get(),
                                         this->strides().get());
    }

...
};
```

Does anyone know what is the usage of operator keyword in C++?

Comment: See especially the part on [conversion operators](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16615725/136208).

Comment: [conversion operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator)

Comment: It performs a conversion to those types, Param<data_t<T>> and CParam<data_t<T>>. It will be called by an explicit cast of class Array to those types or an implicit conversion that fits.